# Replace Value in a Column Using a Loop and Custom Function - R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with a column (named "color") in which every value is "black." I also have created a function that can replace "black" with other colors depending on another column's value (the "growth" column value). I need to create a loop that uses this function to replace the values in the "color" column according to the "growth" value

```
# Create a function
check_it <- function(x) 
  if(x>500){
    return("green")
  } else if(x<0) {
      return("red")
  } else {
    return("blue")
}
```

```
# Create a loop using check_it
for(x in 1:nrow(all_data)) {
     ...
# Given this hint:
# You can use 1:nrow(all_data) as a set of indices 
# to do something like the following inside the loop:
#    all_data[i, "color"] <- 
#    check_it( all_data[i, "growth"] )
```

Any suggestions?

SAMPLE DATA

```
| station_id | timestamp | growth.x | growth.y | color |
--------------------------------------------------------
|     DB1    | 1/14/01   | 59.916   | 59.9164  | black |
--------------------------------------------------------
|     DB1    | 1/14/02   | 316.128  | 316.128  | black |
--------------------------------------------------------
|     DB1    | 1/14/03   | -12.456  | -12.456  | black |
--------------------------------------------------------
|     DB1    | 1/14/04   | 537.443  | 537.443  | black |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for the help! Thanks to the comments I was able to understand that my function wouldn't work without the proper arguments inserted (I just had "x") and didn't tell my function where to look for the "growth" value.

Here's the code I ended up using:

```
check_it <- function(x, ) 
  if(all_data[x, "growth.x"] >500){
    return("green")
  } else if(all_data[x, "growth.x"] <0) {
      return("red")
  } else {
    return("blue")
}

# Create a loop using check_it
for(x in 1:nrow(all_data)) {

   all_data[x, "color"] <- check_it(x, all_data)
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to 1) Simply copy and paste the code and remove the images. 2) Add sample data

Comment: You mention that you tried couple of options so I think it would be great to show what you tried. Also, to make it easier on people who might try to help you, please provide a sample of some data.

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: `transform(data, color = cut(growth.y ,c(-Inf,-1,500,Inf),c('red','blue','green')))`

Comment: @Onyambu - nice solution but this seems to be an exercise for writing basic functions and loops.

Comment: The function won't work without an argument and the variable in the loop has to match what's used in the expression (pay attention to the hint).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, of course there are plenty of solutions to your problem. But since you specifically requested a loop and provided your own function I tried to stick to what you've done so far as much as possible. You have however two `growth`-columns so I took the `growth.y`.

```
datf <- read.table(text="
                        station_id   timestamp   growth.x   growth.y   color  
                        DB1      1/14/01     59.916     59.9164    black  
                        DB1      1/14/02     316.128    316.128    black  
                        DB1      1/14/03      12.456     12.456    black  
                        DB1      1/14/04     537.443    537.443    black", 
                        header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

#I had to change your function a little:

check_it <- function(x, dat) 
  if(dat[x, "growth.y"] >500){
    return("green")
  } else if(dat[x, "growth.y"] < 0) {
    return("red")
  } else {
    return("blue")
  }
```

Now your loop-variable x corresponds to the row index of the `data.frame` and you're looping through it. Before that, this was not the case you just passed a number to your function.

```
#And finally the loop
for(x in 1:nrow(datf)){

  datf[x, "color"] <- check_it(x, datf)

}

> datf
  station_id timestamp growth.x growth.y color
1        DB1   1/14/01   59.916  59.9164  blue
2        DB1   1/14/02  316.128 316.1280  blue
3        DB1   1/14/03   12.456  12.4560  blue
4        DB1   1/14/04  537.443 537.4430 green
```

You should however consider to look at the *apply-function family.